# Mathematica cannot calculate a limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

When I evaluate

```
Limit[E^(-n)*Sum[n^k/(k!),{k,0,n}], n -> ∞]
```

*Mathematica* gives me the result

```
Limit[Gamma[1 + n, n]/(n Gamma[n]), n -> ∞]
```

Actually, the answer is exactly 1/2.

Is there any way to coax *Mathematica* to find the limit?

Comment: That still cannot be solved, even after all those years. Wow.

Answer (score 4):

Taking `GammaRegularized[k + 1, k]` (which is equivalent to the unevaluated expression you obtained) as your function, we can consider a discretized version of your sequence, say `GammaRegularized[2^k + 1, 2^k]`, and then give that to the (undocumented!) function `SequenceLimit[]`, which uses the Shanks transformation:

```
SequenceLimit[Table[N[GammaRegularized[2^k + 1, 2^k], 25], {k, 20}]]
   0.500000000000000000
```

(It's not a proof, but increasing the precision and/or the number of terms of the sequence does yield consistent results.)

If you look within the Numerical Calculus package and see the definition for `NLimit[]`, you'll see that this is essentially the procedure being used within.

Comment: how come Spawn1701D's answer is so inaccurate?

Comment: @chris, I suppose option tweaking would be in order...

Comment: `NLimit[Gamma[1 + n, n]/Gamma[n + 1], n -> Infinity, Terms -> 8]` yields 0.50007

Answer (score 2):

Try with `NLimit`:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

NLimit[Gamma[1 + n, n]/Gamma[n + 1], n -> Infinity]
```

> 0.499858